# In liquibase, is multiple change-set for different table creation in a single databaseChangeLog is better or single change-set for different tables?

Tags: migration, schema, database-migration, liquibase, corda

So I am working on Corda state schema liquibase creation,

```
    object MySchema
    
    object MySchemaV1 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = MySchema.javaClass,
        version = 1, 
        mappedTypes = listOf(
    PersistentChild1::class.java,
    PersistentChild2::class.java
    PersistentChild3::class.java) {
```

Here, each child persistent entity class have separate tables. Which is the best way to create liquibase scripts for MySchema?

means,

1. <createTable tag of each tables under different change set or same change set?
2. Is there any way to split each mappedTypes into different changelog files OR it is not recommended?

Comment: https://forum.liquibase.org/t/which-one-is-recommended-multiple-createtable-commands-in-a-single-changeset-or-each-createtable-in-each-changeset-inside-an-init-xml-file/7116/3

Comment: Another similar question I asked in liquibase forum - above

Answer (score 1):

In terms of liquibase, it doesn't really matter if you create one big or many small change logs - it comes down to your process and prefernces, I'd say.

As all changes always need to be run in the same order, and future changes always added after the last current change set, there isn't any functional difference I am aware of.

So it comes down to:

- one large change set has fewer files to handle, and it is easier to see what goes in initially in which order
- many small change sets might allow slightly better documentation and sign off.

I personally prefer to create change sets that include all changes done at one time (and for a new CorDapp that would be all initial changes before the first release).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Christian.

1) that means you prefer, to have one changeset for all the 3 - tables (in mappedtypes) ?

Comment: 2) my thought process was, how can we split each mappedtype into different changelog files, so that if there is a change in one table, we could add in that particular file alone later.